# Suppose $|A|=n$, let $I_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $F=\left\{f \mid f: I_{n} \rightarrow A\right.$ is bijection $\}$. Then $|F|=n!$.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, proof-writing

The proof is quite long but I think I managed to make it quite readable, what do you think? In general, is a long but still readable proof a lot worse than a short and clear proof? Or is the problem only long/short unreadable proofs?

Do I make any deductions that could be derived from simpler or shorter statements? For example I prove a couple times something is injective/surjective and maybe I've made them unnecessarily long.

Also is it even valid?

**Theorem.** Suppose $|A|=n$, let $I_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $F=\left\{f \mid f: I_{n} \rightarrow A\right.$ is bijection $\}$. Then $|F|=n!$.
*Proof.*
We induct on $n$.

**Base:** $|A|=1$. Then $A=\{a\}$ for some $a$ and clearly $f:\{1\} \rightarrow\{a\}$ is the only bijection, i.e $|F|=1=n!$.

**Step:** Assume true for $n$. Let $|A|=n+1$. Take any $a \in A$ and let $A^{\prime}=A \backslash\{a\}$. Let $F^{\prime}$ be the set of bijections from $I_{n}$ to $A^{\prime}$. Then by IH, since $\left|A^{\prime}\right|=n,\left|F^{\prime}\right|=n!$. Note that

$$
(n+1) !=n! \cdot(n+1)=\left|F^{\prime}\right| \cdot\left|I_{n+1}\right|=\left|F^{\prime} \times I_{n+1}\right|
$$

Therefore to prove $|F|=(n+1)!$, it is sufficient to construct a bijection $F \rightarrow F^{\prime} \times I_{n+1}$. Let $g: I_{n+1} \rightarrow A$ be a bijection in $F$. Let $H: F \rightarrow F^{\prime} \times I_{n+1}$ be defined by $H(g)=(f, i)$, where $f$ is a bijection from $I_{n}$ to $A^{\prime}$, and $i \in I_{n+1}$, $g(i)=a$. The def of $f$ depends on $i$. If $i=n+1$, then $f=g \setminus\{(i, a)\}$ is clearly a bijection $I_{n} \rightarrow A^{\prime}$.
Otherwise, $i \neq n+1$.
Let
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
g(x) & \text { if } x \neq i \\
g(n+1) & \text { if } x=i
\end{array} .\right.
$$

To see that $f$ is bijective, observe that it is just $g$ except
(1) $i$ maps to $g(n+1)$ instead of $g(i)$
(2) $n+1$ is not in the domain
(3) $a$ is not in the range since $g$ is bijective and $g(i)=a$.
Therefore, since $g$ is bijective from $I_{n+1}$ to $A, f$ is bijective from $I_{n}$ to $A^{\prime}$.

We then show that $H$ is bijective. To see it is injective, Let $g_{1}, g_{2}: I_{n+1} \rightarrow A$ be bijections and suppose $H(g_1)=H(g_2)$, i.e $\left(f_{1}, i_{1}\right)=\left(f_{2}, i_{2}\right)$. We consider the two possible definitions of $f_{1}$, depending on $i_{1}$.

Case $1, i_{1}=n+1$.
Then $f_{1}=g_{1} \backslash\left\{\left(i_{1}, a\right)\right\}$. Since $i_{2}=i_{1}, f_{2}=g_{2} \backslash\left\{\left(i_{2}, a\right)\right\}$.
Then $\left(i_{1}, a\right)=\left(i_{2}, a\right)$ and $f_{1}=f_{2}$, so $g_{1}=g_{2}$.

Case $2, i_{1} \neq n+1$.
Then $$f_{1}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}g_{1}(x) & \text { if } x \neq i_{1} \\ g_{1}(n+1) & \text { if } x=i_{1}\end{array}\right.$$ $$f_{2}(x)= \begin{cases}g_{2}(x) & \text { if } x \neq i_{2} \\ g_{2}(n+1) & \text { if } x=i_{2}\end{cases}$$

Let $j \in I_{n}, j \neq i_{1}$. Then $g_{1}(j)=f_{1}(j)=f_{2}(j)=g_{2}(j)$. Since we also have that $g_{1}\left(i_{1}\right)=a=g_{2}\left(i_{2}\right)$ and $g_{1}(n+1)=f_{1}(x)=f_{2}(x)=g_{1}(n+1)$, it follows that $g_{1}=g_{2}$.

To see $H$ is surjective, let $f: I_{n} \rightarrow A^{\prime}$ be bijective and $i \in I_{n+1}$. We consider two cases for $i$, which depend on how we define $g$.

Case $1 . i=n+1$.
Then $g=f \cup\{(i, a)\}$ is a bijection $I_{n+1} \rightarrow A$, so $H(g)=\left(f^{\prime}, i^{\prime}\right)$ where $g\left(i^{\prime}\right)=a=g(i)$.  Then $f^{\prime}=g \backslash\{(i, a)\}=f \cup\{(i, a)\} \backslash\{(i, a)\}=f$.

Case $2, i \neq n+1$.
Define $g: I_{n+1} \rightarrow A$ by

$$
g(x)= \begin{cases}f(x) & \text { if } x \neq n+1 \wedge x \neq i \\ f(i) & \text { if } x=n+1 \\ a & \text { if } x=i\end{cases}
$$

Notice that $g$ is just $f$ except
(1) $i$ maps to $a$ instead of $f(i)$
(2) $n+1$ is in the domain and it maps to $f(i)$
So clearly it is bijective.

Then $H(g)=\left(f^{\prime}, i^{\prime}\right)$ where $f^{\prime} \in F, i^{\prime} \in I_{n+1}$. First, $i^{\prime}$ is defined as $g\left(i^{\prime}\right)=a$, and since $g(i)=a, i=i^{\prime}$. Then since $i^{\prime} \neq n+1, f^{\prime}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}g(x) & \text { if } x \neq i^{\prime} \\ g(n+1) & \text { if } x=i^{\prime}\end{array}\right.$.
Let $j \in I_{n}$. If $j=i$, then $f^{\prime}(j)=g(n+1)$, and by def of $g, g(n+1)=f(i)$, so $f^{\prime}(j)=f(j)$. If $j \neq i$, then $f^{\prime}(j)=g(j)=f(j)$. Therefore $f^{\prime}=f$, and thus $H(g)=(f, i)$; hence $H$ is surjective.